# Best way to check if Google Play purchase has been refunded/voided?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play-services

This is for a libGDX Android project. I have my in app payment setup but how can check if a refund has been processed? Using the In App Billing Helper, I tried something like:

```
inventory.getPurchase(SKU_FULLVER).getPurchaseState()
```

But this returns null for a refunded purchase. I was expecting a number (1, 2, or 3 as per the codes mentioned in Table 6 here: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html). Is this the correct way to check if a purchase has been refunded or is there a better way?